# Expansion of the functions like $f(x)^{g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

If I have two function $f$ and $g$ with $f(x)^{g(x)}$, with $\text{dom}\ f(x)=\{x \in \Bbb R \ \mid f(x)>0\}$ and $g$ defined into your domain, we know that:

$$\psi(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)\ln f(x)}\tag 1$$

But developing Taylor's series, it is true that
$$e^x=1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+x^4/24+x^5/120+\dotsb \ \tag 2$$

For the functions of the tipologies $\psi(x)$ I expand using the $(2)$ ,

$$e^{h(x)}=1+h(x)+(h(x))^2/2+\dotsb \tag 3$$

where $h(x)=g(x)\ln f(x) \ $ or are there other ways to expand, easily, $\psi(x)$ from $(1)$?

Comment: In third member $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @zkutch Yes, I have forgotten to copy from $e^x$. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)^{g(x)}=\exp\left(g(x)\ln(f(x))\right)$$
$$h(x):=g(x)\ln(f(x))$$
$$e^{h(x)}=e^{h(0)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n(h'(0),h''(0),...,h^{(n-1)}(0))\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Where $B_n(a_1,...,a_n)$ is the [complete Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Examples_2)

In your case
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}h(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}g(x)\ln(f(x))=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}g^{(n-k)}(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k}\ln(f(x))$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k}\ln(f(x))=\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(k-1)!}{f(x)^k}B_{k,j}(f'(x),...,f^{(k-j+1)}(x))$$

Where $B_{k,j}(a_1,...,a_{k-j+1})$ is the [incomplete exponential Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials)

Comment: Thank you vey much.  It is, however, very complicated to understand. I have not studied the series for several years, and I did not know Bell's polynomial. +1